# How to wait indefinitely for the DOM load?

Tags: javascript

The function:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded" , function(){});
```

or

```
window.addEventListener("load" , function(){});
```

It allows me to do anything, as fast as it loads the DOM with some particularities between both methods.

This is `"as soon as"`

But, how can I wait, indefinitely, to load the DOM?

and just load the DOM, execute the function?
Let me explain: Imagine I have a function, anyone.

```
cube cube = n => Math.pow (n, 3);
if (document.readyState === 'complete') cube (3);
```

Suppose the cube function is FUNDAMENTAL in my code.

But if the DOM has not loaded, the function will not have been executed.

So, how can I wait, indefinitely until the DOM loads, and postpone another function, which acts in response to this main function (cube)

So, if my script reached that point and the DOM did not load, all those functions would NOT have any value.

My focus instead of

> "If this happens, do this"

is:

> "Wait for this to happen, and do this"

Comment: have you considered using a promise?

Comment: `document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {/*Everything is loaded.*/})` iirc, this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step one: create a variable visible both in DOMContentLoaded handler and in your `cube` function. Its value should be a promise resolved by that handler. For example:

```
const DOMLoaded = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", resolve);
  // consider creating reject-on-timeout 
  // with something like setTimeout(reject, 60000 * 10);
});
```

Step two: handle this promise resolve by calling cube():

```
DOMLoaded.then(() => cube(3));
```

Comment: So, this waits indefinitely? and if I apply the reject, will the wait be a maximum of 60000 * 10 seconds?

Comment: 1) yes, 2) 10 minutes.